# Appengine Data Validation Pattern?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I am pretty new to appengine and I am interested to hear what are the best practices when it comes to data validation.

First off, this is my models.py

```
class Event(db.Model):  
  name = db.StringProperty()
  event_type = db.ReferenceProperty(EventType)
  data = db.TextProperty()
```

Ideally, I would like to enforce `name` and `event_type` to have `required=True`.

However, I also come from a rails background and this is my edit_event.html (used for both creating and editing a event):

```
<form method="POST">   

  name: <input type="text" name="name" value="{{ event.name or '' }}"/>
  <br/>

  event type:
  <select name="event_type">
    {% for event_type in event_types %}
      <option value={{ event_type.key().id_or_name() }}>
      {{- event_type.name -}}
      </option>
    {% endfor %}
  </select>
  <br/>

  data: <input type="text" name="data" value="{{ event.data or '' }}"/>
  <br/>

  <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>

</form>
```

And this is what my view function looks like:

```
@app.route('/events/new/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def new_event():
  if request.method == 'GET':
    return render_template('edit_event.html',
                           event=Event(),
                           event_types=db.Query(EventType).fetch(None))
  else:
    _update_event(Event(), request.form)
    return redirect(url_for('list_events'))


@app.route('/events/<int:event_id>/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def edit_event(event_id):
  event = Event.get_by_id(event_id)
  if request.method == 'GET':
    return render_template('edit_event.html',
                           event=event,
                           event_types=db.Query(EventType).fetch(None))
  else:
    _update_event(event, request.form)
    return redirect(url_for('list_events'))
```

(NOTE: I've left out _update_event for the sake of breivity)

As you can see, if I enforce `required=True` in the model, `event=Event()` in `new_event()` will raise an Exception.

If I don't include `event=Event()` in `new_event()`, I am getting an error that `event is not defined`.

What is a good way to have both required=True and a reusable edit_event.html that works for both new_event and edit_event?

**OF COURSE, if I have `required=True` and `default=X` it's kind of defeating the purpose.**

Answer (score 2):

You have a few choices

You could have a sentinal value for default, and a property specific validator that forces a validation failure if the default value is set at the time you call `put()` or use a `_pre_put_hook` to do final model validation.

Alternately use a forms package (Wtforms/deform or whatever the framework you are using supplies) where you enforce this type of business logic in the forms schema.

Often you have constraints on a model that you can't enforce/describe in the model and need to rely on the form validation phase to do this for you.  For instance if values in different properties have dependencies on each other.